# 2-factor authentication code generator in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, authentication

Google has an Authenticator app that, given a secret and the time, shows a 6-digit code. The code cycles every 30 seconds. I wrote an implementation in Python 3 (can be run in Python 2 with some changes) that optionally generates a qrcode for a new user and/or just shows the current code displayed in the Authenticator app.

```
import hmac, base64, struct, hashlib, time, pyqrcode, random, sys, os

def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = h[19] & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h

def get_totp_token(secret):
    return get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no=int(time.time())//30)

# This works whenever I run it, but I'm not 100% sure it conforms to RFC standards
# Also, I'm not sure if the secret is every allowed to not be 16 bytes
def generate_secret(length=16):
    random_secret = ""
    characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"
    for _ in range(length):
        random_secret += random.choice(characters)
    return random_secret

# Pads secret with zeroes and separates with a space
def format_secret(secret, to_length=6):
    padded = '0'*(6-len(str(secret)))+str(secret)
    return padded[:3] + ' ' + padded[3:]

# Sets up a user given a label, username, and generates/takes a secret
# Is there a better way to do the "y/n: " stuff?
def setup_user():
    label = input("Label: ").replace(' ', '%20')
    user = input("User: ").replace(' ', '%20')
    secret = input("Auto-generate secret? y/n: ")

    if secret.lower() == "y":
        secret = generate_secret()
    else: 
        secret = input("Secret: ")

    return label, user, secret

secret = "DID NOT SET SECRET"

# Again, is there a better way to do the "y/n: "?
if input("Setup user? y/n: ").lower() == "y":
    label, user, secret = setup_user()

    if input("Show qr-code? y/n: ").lower().strip() == "y":
        # I'm unsure if this URL breaks when certain characters are in the label or username
        qr_url = "otpauth://totp/%s:%s?secret=%s&issuer=%s" % (label, user, secret, label)
        url = pyqrcode.create(qr_url)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        # Is it possible to make the qrcode smaller when printed in Terminal/Console?
        print(url.terminal(quiet_zone=1))
else:
    secret = input("Secret: ")
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print("User secret: ", secret)

sys.stdout.write("\r%s" % format_secret(get_totp_token(secret)))
sys.stdout.flush()
# This next line is my code to time-sync the timer. I'm not sure if it actually works though. 
# I think it might have to do with using modular arithmetic on a float
time.sleep(1 - time.time() % 1)

while True: 
    # These next couple of lines format a progress bar for how many seconds are left until a new code.
    seconds = int(30 - time.time() % 30)
    lines = "-" * int(seconds)# / 3)
    blocks = "█" * (30 - len(lines))
    progress = "|" + blocks + lines + "|"

    sys.stdout.write("\r%s" % format_secret(get_totp_token(secret)) + "\t" + progress)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(1)
```

This uses the `pyqrcode` library, which does not ship standard with Python.

I noticed that sometimes, the code does not change exactly when it does in the Authenticator app. This may be a problem with my time-syncing code.

What are your thoughts on quality of code, usability, pythonic-ness, and correctness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code quality

- Each `import` should have its own, seperate line:

  ```
  import hmac
  import base64
  import struct
  import hashlib
  import time
  import pyqrcode
  import random
  import sys
  import os
  ```
- Top-level functions should be seperated using two blank lines:

  ```
  def foo():
      foobar()


  def bar():
      foobar()
  ```
- A lot of your comments should actually be [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

### Security

- **Don't use the `random` module for security purposes.** Skimming through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), red banners warn you not to use it for security purposes and instead to use [the secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets). Note that `secrets` is only part of the standard library in Python 3.6 and upwards. If you need to run this on other versions of Python, which is quite likely, make use of `random.SystemRandom` (or `os.urandom()` directly).
- Use `getpass.getpass()` instead of plain `input()` for gathering secrets like passwords or private codes. [[getpass documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)]

### General recommendations

- Since `pyqrcode` isn't part of the standard library, you may want to wrap `import pyqrcode` in a `try:/except:` statement:

  ```
  try:
      import pyqrcode
  except ModuleNotFoundError:
      print("Couldn't import pyqrcode.")
      sys.exit(1)
  ```
- If you plan to release this as a module, it's a very good idea to add documentation (docstrings, as well as a README for quick reference), so others understand how the code works and how they should use it.

Comment: What do you think about the `y/n: ` stuff? Do you think there is a better way to do this –– to get some boolean value?

Comment: Your solution is actually pretty good. There's a couple of ways to handle these types of situations. You could try making it a bit more explicit by defining behavior in an enum (```options = {"y": foo(), "n": bar()}```). If you don't want to use that, you may want to check ```if input("Setup user? [y/n]: ").lower().strip() in ("yes", "y"):```, so users have a bit more space.

Comment: The most important issue I think is with my time-syncing code: I am not sure, but does using `%` on a float cause rounding/accuracy problems?